# Documentation with images - what is the most git-friendly approach?

Tags: git, word

When documenting software I traditionally write a plain text file (like a README.txt) which works well, but unfortunately cannot contain images like HTML can.  Unfortunately images must be stored as separate files with a normal HTML document (using <a href=".../foo.png">) which give unnecessary clutter.

The "Save a single web-page" in Internet Explorer use MIME HTML (MHTML) to save all resources within a single file.  The requirement of having to use a browser to read it, is not a impediment these days.  Apparently Opera and Word support editing these documents directly.

We use git for our source code, hence the differences as seen by git between two edits of the same documents should not be large to avoid unnecessary disk usage and unusable diff's when looking at the document outside the MTHML editor.

What is the best mainstream HTML editor for producing git-friendly MHTML files?

Comment: I for one, would prefer the images file to be external. Firstly, that would allow me to use my preferred text editor (VIM) on the files rather then fighting with an editor. Secondly, I often have external processes generate images. For example, I might have a class diagram generated by parsing the code. It easy to have a script update the images when they are external but very difficult if the images are internal.

Comment: Don't do that. There's no reason to avoid external files. Clutter can be reduced by folders. Not using external files will complicate matters unnecessarily.

Comment: Looks like no one has a *real* answer!

Comment: @WinstonEwert do you have any input relevant to what I actually ask?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, if I had something that actually answered your question I would have posted it as an answer. I think the best solution is not to embed the images. Nevertheless, if I knew of a tool that would help I would tell you. But I don't.

Comment: Actually, another thought occurs to me. Git supports custom merge drivers. i.e. you can provide your own merge tool. I don't know anything about it, but you might be able to develop a merge tool that understands that mhtml format and handles merges nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I'd store images and text separately in source control; this way, even though your images are binary blobs (and thus not handled efficiently), you won't have a lot of small changes on binary files, provided you don't change the images themselves much.

Choose a documentation source format that fits your needs - HTML, Markdown, DocBook, LaTeX, etc. - and store only the sources (and the images you need to include) in source control. Then, just like with the code itself, you set up a build system, which allows anyone to build documentation in a consumable format (probably several of them, e.g. multi-file HTML, MHTML, PDF) from the sources.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Would you happen to also have an answer to "What is the best mainstream HTML editor for producing git-friendly MHTML files?"?

Comment: -1 for not answering the question. I wouldn't do it either, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Unfortunately I am not aware of any usable editor that produces MHTML directly, let alone one that produces version control friendly MHTML. Hence my suggestion to generate (M)HTML from a version control friendly source format.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be assuming that MHTML is the only way of embedding images into HTML. On the basis that that is an assumption rather than MHTML being an absolute requirement, I'd suggest using HTML and [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). That allows you to edit the text and get diffs using a standard text editor; if you're going to be editing the images a lot you'll probably want a text editor which supports base-64 en/decoding. Notepad++ has a standard plugin to do this, and I'm sure other editors targeted at programmers will too.

I should note that I've never used this approach for documentation, but I have used it for `app_offline.htm` pages.

Comment: If you have seen any other format with reasonable editors (i.e. not seeing raw image data) I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you absolutely don't want external images, you could **embed images in HTML as base64** ([here is an online converter](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter)).

But I would personally rather have files as HTML (or better, Markdown) with images separated, and **export/print to PDF** if/when a single file is requested, that is easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would you happen to also have an answer to "What is the best mainstream HTML editor for producing git-friendly MHTML files?"?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the approach with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) - that way, you can have HTML with images, and the "original" will still be in plain textual format, easy for diff.

Comment: Is this in a single file as with MTHML or are the images external?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, no Markdown can basically be seen as a simplified HTML syntax in this context

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Markdown files are plain text files, with the links to images being absolute or relative paths to the files. Images are separate than markdown (or html) files. The advantage of markdown is that it's plain text, no tags, and therefore can be easily diffed, or just printed out as they are - they're quite readable. Also, their popularity is growing quite fast the last few years.

Comment: @Idigas, even though Markdown is nice, I still want my images embedded so I only have a single document.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - (Ldigas) Good luck then! I don't know of any format that embeeds images, and still makes it easy to let's say, do a diff. May I ask, what is the reason for such a decision? You're not only making it hard to compare different revisions, you're also making it hard to vcs it (version control is really ment for files that you can compare)), so you must have some strong reason for doing so.

Comment: @ldigas To keep it simple as you do not appear to know this format, MHTML is "just" HTML but with internal references to other MIME-entities (like images) in the document instead of to external files.  Would you consider HTML-files diff'able?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Yes, but it is not something I look forward to (HTML diff) :/

Answer (score 0):

Use RTF format. Unlike DOC/DOCX it's neither binary nor compressed, so it DIFFS quite nicely. Inserting images puts them at the end of the file and reference inside, so it's as source control friendly as possible.

Comment: Would you happen to know a good editor which produce diff-friendly RTF-files?